# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float',Thanks a lot

Tags: numpy

```
def lamb_0(x):

    return (1-x)/2

def lamb_1(x):

    return (1+x)/2

x = np.array([0.5773502691896257645091488,-0.5773502691896257645091488])

Right_item_2 = (1/2)*np.array([(-1/2)*[(C_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[0])+C_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[0]))*(R_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[0])+R_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[0]))+(C_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[1])+C_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[1]))*(R_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[1])+R_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[1]))],(1/2)*[(C_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[0])+C_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[0]))*(R_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[0])+R_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[0]))+(C_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[1])+C_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[1]))*(R_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[1])+R_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[1]))]],dtype=float)
```

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
#mark:C_n,R_n,S_n are arraies in 2 dimension
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976467/typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float

Comment: Why the [], `[(C_n[0,j] ...` ?  Make sure that last line is correct, step by step.  The error says you've created a list, and trying to multiply it by a float, such as `1/2`.  `[]` make a list.  `()` just group math expressions.  Don't confuse the two.

Comment: That is some extremely obscure and unreadable code. Surely there has to be a better way to do this, right? There seems to be a lot of repetition, there’s probably a way to rewrite it using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

First break the calculation up into several lines.

```
Right_item_2 = (1/2)*np.array([
    (-1/2)*[        # Here you multiply a list by (-1/2). Should it be ( not [?

        (C_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[0])+C_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[0]))*
        (R_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[0])+R_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[0]))+
        (C_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[1])+C_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[1]))*
        (R_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[1])+R_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[1]))
    ],
    (1/2)*[         # Here you multiply a list by (-1/2)

        (C_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[0])+C_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[0]))*
        (R_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[0])+R_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[0]))+
        (C_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[1])+C_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[1]))*
        (R_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[1])+R_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[1]))
    ]
],dtype=float)
```

As far as I can see both calculations are the same, `res` below.

```
res = (C_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[0])+C_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[0]))*
      (R_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[0])+R_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[0]))+
      (C_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[1])+C_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[1]))*
      (R_n[0,j]*lamb_0(x[1])+R_n[1,j]*lamb_1(x[1]))

Right_itm_2 = np.array[-.5*res, .5*res]
```

There's still scope to make the `res` calculation more readable and less repetitive